# show fit information on plot

Tags: plotting, fitting, data, visualization

After performing a fit in Mathematica, I would like to show the fitted parameters in a box on the plot showing the fitted function. How would I go about achieving that?

Here is a MWE:

```
func[a_, b_, x_] := a*x + b;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[{{1, 1}, {5, 5}, {2, 3}}, func[
    a,
    b,
    x],
   {{a, 1}, {b, 0}}, x];



Plot[Normal[nlm[t]], {t, 0, 1.0}, PlotRange -> Full]
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

Comment: You can start from `Plot[Normal[nlm[t]], {t, 0, 1.0}, PlotRange -> Full, Epilog -> Inset[nlm["ParameterTable"]]]` and read the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As b.gatessucks comments you can use inset. You can also use `PlotLegends` and customize, e.g.

```
tab = nlm["ParameterTable"]
plt = Show[
  Plot[nlm[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> Full, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{Blue}, {Normal@nlm[t]}, 
      LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 3}, 
      LegendFunction -> (Column[{#, tab}, Frame -> True] &)], {0.3, 
      0.8}], Frame -> True], 
  ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {5, 5}, {2, 3}}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}], 
  PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]